# Internal soundcard sometimes card 0 and sometimes card 2 with 2 usb mics

Tags: audio, alsa

I can't get a consistent setting for my internal soundcard. BCM2835 is sometimes card 2 and then I'll reboot and it'll be card 0. Driving me nuts, hard to set the default when it's jumping around. Is there anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to some .conf file in `/etc/modprobe.d/`:

```
options snd slots=snd-bcm2835,snd-usb-audio,snd-usb-audio
```

(in whatever order you want)